# Linked List Java

Tags: java, linked-list

this is a homework problem, but not really to be graded, just something to be used in future projects. I'm having problems with getting to display what I have in my list/nodes.
Mainly I get an error when calling displayList.

Merge combines lists into new one which includes all list 1 and 2 items.

Union includes only one of each duplicate from list 1 and 2.

Intersection only includes duplicates from list 1 and 2, not from same list.

Note in merge method the code in note form is just an alternative form of current one I believe.

```
//Kevin Clement
//Homework 2

   class LinkedListHomework
   {
      public static ListNode Merge(ListNode List1, ListNode List2)
      {
         ListNode head, tail;
         head = tail = new ListNode( "Hi1");

         while(List1 != null && List2 != null)
         {
            if(List1.getItem().toString().compareTo(List2.getItem().toString()) < 0)
            {
               tail.setNext(new ListNode(List1.getItem()));
               List1 = List1.getNext();
            }
            else
            {
               tail.setNext(new ListNode(List2.getItem()));
               List2 = List2.getNext();
            }
            tail = tail.getNext();
         }

      // while(List1 != null)
      // {
      // tail.setNext(new ListNode(List1.getItem()));
      // tail = tail.getNext();
      // List1 = List1.getNext();
      // }
      // 
      // while(List2 != null)
      // {
      // tail.setNext(new ListNode(List2.getItem()));
      // tail = tail.getNext();
      // List2 = List2.getNext();
      // }
         return head.getNext();


      }




   // public static ListNode Union(ListNode List1, ListNode List2)
   // {
   // 
   // 
   // 
   // }

   // // public static ListNode Intersection(ListNode List1, ListNode YList2)
   // {
   // 
   // }

      public void displayList()
      {
         ListNode temp = head;
         System.out.print("head");
         while(temp != null)
         {
            System.out.print("--> " + temp.getItem());
            temp = temp.getNext();
         }
         System.out.print("\n\n");
      }


      public static void main(String args[])
      {

         ListNode A = new ListNode("Adam", new ListNode("Andrew", new ListNode("Kyle", new ListNode("Luc", new ListNode("Michael", new ListNode("Tony"))))));
         ListNode B = new ListNode("Adam", new ListNode("Fallon", new ListNode("Jim", new ListNode("Kyle", new ListNode("Nina", new ListNode("Shea", new ListNode("Tony")))))));

         displayList(A);
         A.displayList();




      }

   }
```

Okay here are my errors, I feel that copying them down will be more helpful to you guys than me trying to explain what's wrong.

```
LinkedListHomework.java:61: cannot find symbol  
symbol  : variable head 
location: class LinkedListHomework  
         ListNode temp = head;  
                         ^  
LinkedListHomework.java:78: displayList() in LinkedListHomework cannot be applied to (ListNode)
         displayList(A);  
         ^  
LinkedListHomework.java:79: cannot find symbol  
symbol  : method displayList()  
location: class ListNode  
            A.displayList();  
             ^  
3 errors
```

Comment: Formatting, formatting, formatting. It really does pay out (for instance, after this comment, I shall leave this question because, if *you* don't show hubris... not worth it for me ;-)

Comment: What @pst said. If you want to ignore formatting guidelines, you'd better be enough of a badass to not need to ask for help.

Comment: so what is your specific question, besides "do it for me?"

Comment: Please explain formatting, what is wrong with my formatting? I'll happily change it if I knew. Also will edit my question because i left out parts. sorry.

Comment: @KevinClement Indentation shows structure and aids in communicating intent.

Comment: When you get an error, it's helpful to say what the error actually is. We can't actually see your monitor from here. So you don't have to put your pants back on.

Comment: @Kevin: First of all when you have code in your post, select the code and press the code button in the toolbar. This will tab in your code and cause it to be formatted properly. However also your code is improperly tabbed to begin with so for ease of reading we'd appreciate if you apply proper tabbing. We're friendly people here - by default we want to be helpful. When you ask a question you just have to make sure it stays that way ;)

Comment: Add tabbed spaces for every block, Write a short comment on what you are trying to do in each block ( all the places if possible )and what is the error you are getting. This is something highly recommended (infact required !)

Comment: @bsoundra For this code I would not recommend comments; then we have to decide if the code matches the comments; which was intended, the code or the comments, etc.

Comment: I apologize for horrible formatting, I had not indented in my program when copying over. Basically the errors I'm getting are related to my displayList. I realize that I can't just send my list into the displayList method the way the method is written right now, but I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: [Coding Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Answer (score 1):

The first error is with the line `ListNode temp = head;` :  `head` has not been declared.

The second error is because you're trying to call `displayList` with an argument:  it takes no arguments.  Also, it's not a static method -- it must be called on an object.

The third error is because you're trying to call `displayList` on an object of class `ListNode`, while `displayList` actually belongs to class `LinkedListHomework`.

Comment: And trying to call an instance method from a static method.